# Please first use equation (3) and solve $̇()$ of roly-poly toy model

Tags: physics

Question:Please first use equation  (3)  and solve  $̇()$

By definition:
let $a$ =second derivative of $\theta$

$b$ =first derivative of theta

Here, $ℎ$  is  the  $y$-coordinate  of  $$  and  we  take  these  parameters:
$ℎ= (3/8), _ =(83/320)^2,  = 0.5,   =250,  (=0)= 60$ degree .

$$
a=-hm\sin(\theta)(g+rb^2)/(I_c+m(r^2+h^2-2hr\cos(\theta)))\ \ \ \ (eq3)
$$

the definition of eq3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDPdU.png)

we  further simplify the roly-poly toy  on the    plane, where  point  $$  is the
center  of  gravity,  $$  is  the  geometric center  of  the  hemisphere,  $ℎ$  is  the  distance
between  $$  and  $$,  $$  is the gravity of this hemisphere,  $$  is the contacting point,
$$  is the radius of the hemisphere,  $$  is the variable to describe the movement of this
hemisphere, the normal force and the friction from the ground to the hemisphere are
respectively  $$  and  $$.

the graph of roly-poly toy model

[image]

attempt:I just simplify the eq3 and put theta(t=0) =60 degree into the eq 3,

then I solve first derivative of theta (t=0)is (surd of 15)/3 and hc(t=0) is 13/16r,but I don't know how to find the value of theta(t),first derivative of theta(t) and hc(t).

plz help me, thx!

Comment: Please. Use mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

As

$$
C = A + (h\sin\theta,r-h\cos\theta)
$$

we have

$$
\dot C = \dot A + (h\cos\theta,h\sin\theta)\dot\theta = (-r,0)\dot\theta+(h\cos\theta,h\sin\theta)\dot\theta
$$

and now

$$
L = \frac 12m\dot C\cdot\dot C+\frac 12I_c\dot\theta^2-m g(r-h\cos\theta)
$$

the movement equations are obtained with

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\theta}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial\theta}=0
$$

giving

$$
\ddot\theta+\frac{h m \sin \theta \left(g+r \dot \theta ^2\right)}{m \left(h^2+r^2\right)-2 h m r \cos \theta +I_c}=0
$$
etc.